# array_search returns incorrect position

Tags: php, arrays, search

By searching the community and Googleing I can only see issues with array_search loose search resulting integer 0 to be equalled to a string.

However in my case theres no zero and strict search still doesn't seem to help.

Array:

```
$data= array(
            "13" => array(
                "start" => array(
                    0 => "36000",
                    1 => "43200",
                ),
                "end" => array(
                    0 => "43200",
                    1 => "50400",
                ),
            ),
            "14" => array(
                "start" => array(
                    0 => "36000",
                    1 => "43200",
                ),
                "end" => array(
                    0 => "43200",
                    1 => "50400",
                ),
            ),
        );
```

function:

```
foreach ($data as &$area) {
            foreach ($area['start'] as $key => &$start_time) {
                if (($pos = array_search($start_time, $area['end'], true) !== false)) {
                    $area['end'][$pos] = $area['end'][$key];
                    unset($area['start'][$key]);
                    unset($area['end'][$key]);
                }
            }
        }
```

desired output:

```
$data= array(
            "13" => array(
                "start" => array(
                    0 => "36000",
                ),
                "end" => array(
                    0 => "50400",
                ),
            ),
            "14" => array(
                "start" => array(
                    0 => "36000",
                ),
                "end" => array(
                    0 => "50400",
                ),
            ),
        );
```

what I get instead:

```
$data= array(
            "13" => array(
                "start" => array(
                    0 => "36000",
                ),
                "end" => array(
                    0 => "43200",
                ),
            ),
            "14" => array(
                "start" => array(
                    0 => "36000",
                ),
                "end" => array(
                    0 => "43200",
                ),
            ),
        );
```

What I intend to achieve with the above function is to combine the consecutive time slots and as it can be seen, the first matching start time in the end is $data[13]['start'][1] = 43200, which matches with the position ..['end'][0], so therefore I'm expecting the $pos returned to also be 0, but the $pos returned is 1 and the wrong element gets treated.

**Problem in detail**
The $data array is dynamic and will not always be this. Even though the matching $start_time value in "end" array can clearly be found at position 0, the $pos value returned is instead 1.

Have been struggling with this for quite some time now and am unable to find a fault, hope someone else will.

Best,

Alari

Comment: can you type the desired output ?

Comment: @Frayne Konok: What it's supposed to do is check if the $start_time can be found in the $area['end'] array, if not, then do nothing, but if it does find it, sotre the returned key as $pos variable to be processed inside. but as the array_search can return 0 positsion for the key found, I have to do a strict comparison for when it's not false (whish is array_search return value for when nothing is found.

Comment: @Kr Bm: Will make the desired output as a edit asap

Comment: Out of interest, why are you using `&$area` and `&$start_time` by reference rather than simply by value?

Comment: Made the update
@MarkBaker: I wish that the changes made are reflected to the original $data variable

Comment: I don't understand, what am I doing wrong, why all the downvotes? I have clearly done my research and have provided sample data..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because of operator precedence. !== has more precedence over =. So, in your if statement `$pos` is effectively getting assigned the result of `array_search($start_time, $area['end'], true) !== false` which is 1.
Just change your if statement to this and it should work

```
if (($pos = array_search($start_time, $area['end'], true)) !== false) {
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Works like a charm and very well explained! I must've misplaced the brackets, as that's what I was going for and for the life of me could'nt figure out. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

This should work :

**PHP**

```
    foreach ($data as &$area) {
        foreach ($area['start'] as $key => &$start_time) {
            if (($pos = array_search($start_time, $area['end'], true) !== false)) {
                $val = $area['end'][$key];
                unset($area['start'][$key]);
                unset($area['end'][$key]);
                $area['end'][0] = $val;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I can't set the $area['end'][0] but have to set the $area['end'][$pos] element, because it may not be 0, it has to be the location where the $start_time value was found in the "end" array, which in this case is returning a 1 instead of the key 0, where it actually is.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this code, it's simple and work in your case

```
foreach ( $data as &$item ){
        ksort($item['start']);
        ksort($item['end']);
        if ( $item['start'][1] == $item['end'][0] ){
            $item['end'][0] = $item['end'][1]; 
            unset($item['end'][1]); 
            unset($item['start'][1]); 
        }
    }
```

Comment: the $data array is dynamic and I must set the element in which position the $start_time was found, which in this array case is 0 but the value returned for some reason is 0

Comment: then you should use more positions of `$data` so i can understand better

Comment: for instance all the 0 and 1 position values could be flipped

Comment: then you can use `ksort()` before the `if`condition